# Google SignInButton does not fire when using onClick in XML

Tags: android, android-layout, onclick, android-xml, android-button

I have a simple layout file that contains only one button:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="signIn"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And in my MainActivity, I have this method:

```
public void signIn(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

But nothing happens. I have also tried to add:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

But is not working. If set on click listener on the button, it works. How to set onClick directly from the layout file?

Comment: Why don't use the OnClickListener if it works ?

Comment: Because it's more simple that way. Why do use all that boiler plate when I can simply add `android:onClick="signIn"`. Can you help me with a solution?

Comment: Try to replace `getApplicationContext()` with `MainActivity.this`

Comment: @Johann67 Even if I do that, I get the same result.

Comment: PLEASE DO NOT guess code. Read the official documentation regarding `gms.common.SignInButton`. You're required to attach an onClickListener in Java code

Comment: A simple click listener is considered boilerplate? Why?

Comment: @barotia Because I need to write so many lines of code instead of adding a simple property to a button.

Comment: @Zun Thanks for the hint ;) I will.

Comment: Right, if you wan't to reduce line of code, use kotlin :D

Comment: Or, at least lambdas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SignInButton is a custom view which extend View component. The [doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in) indicates to use the `setOnClickListener` directly in your activity or fragment.

Look the [SignInButton source code](https://github.com/jaredrummler/snet-decompiled/blob/master/decompiled/com/google/android/gms/common/SignInButton.java). `onClick` is override and need a `mClientListener` to work. The only way to set the `mClientListener`, it's to use the `setOnClickListener`.

Simply use the OnClick listener directly in your activity or fragment :

```java
signInButton = (SignInButton)findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
signInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: Thanks but I think you don't understand. I already did that before posting the question and it works, but this is not what I want. I want using the ,XML file. Is there any solution?

Comment: I undestand what you want to do. But, as i say, `onClick` attribute can be override and disabled by the `SignInButton`. So, no other solution.

Comment: "can be override" or it is? I'm really confused now. Are you sure that there is no other solution? Can you please share some docs? Thanks

Comment: Ok, look the SignInButton source code here : https://github.com/jaredrummler/snet-decompiled/blob/master/decompiled/com/google/android/gms/common/SignInButton.java . `onClick` is override and need a `mClientListener` to work. The only way to set the `mClientListener`, it's to use the `setOnClickListener`.

Comment: You're right. I have also found now [this](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/SignInButton). It clearly states for that. Please add this resource to your question so I can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

OnClickListener is working fine. I tried this.

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="signInButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        />

    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java code:

```
 public void signInButton(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: I think you don't understand. I already did that before posting the question and it works, but this not what I want. I want using the ,XML file.